# Как сделать чат окно как в телеграме?

Tags: python, pyqt

Пишу приложение на PyQt, не могу понять как сделать такое окно? [image: Чат]

Я так понимаю можно сделать QTableWidget и там 2 колонки, выровнять их 50/50 по ширине и на каждый месседж вставлять новый рядок, если от другого юзера то 1 колонка это его месседж, 2 колонка пустая. Если от себя, то 2 колонка это мой месседж, 1 пустая. Так удобно как по мне. Но как реализовать это в коде я не знаю. Прошу помочь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать двухсторонний чат в QT (PyQt)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1408239/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2-qt-pyqt)

Comment: Injustive, отвечает ли ответ указанный в ссылке первого комментария на ваш вопрос?